# How do I turn OFF ctrl key highlighting mouse pointer?

Tags: 18.04, system-settings

ubuntu 18.04
no "life upgrade" applications installed

somewhere in the settings I turned on the "locate cursor by pressing CTRL" option that shows bright animation around cursor on pressing the button

It seems that it causes ctrl key no longer be readable by applications, so I want to turn it off.
and I can't find it in the settings

where can it be?

Answer (score 4):

In Gnome you have to go to open the `Tweaks` application

Or from the console run

```
$ gnome-tweaks
```

Look for the option "Show location of pointer", in the section "Keyboard and Mouse